# Assign to global shiny environment in package

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app (bundled as part of a package) where at the beginning of the server function I create a bunch of reactive data frames that later get used in other parts of the app.

Since quite a few dataframes get created, I wanted to make a simple `setup_data()` function that could be called at the beginning, in order to help keep the app code tidy. However, since the dfs are created inside a function, I need to use either `<<-` or `assign` to make sure they're available in Shiny's server environment.

```
library(shiny)

setup_data <- function(){
  reactiveDat1 <<- shiny::reactiveValues()
  reactiveDat1$mydf <<- data.frame(x = 1, y = 2)

  reactiveDat2 <<- shiny::reactiveValues()
  reactiveDat2$mydf <<- data.frame(x = 5, y = 10)
}

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel(""),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
      ),

      mainPanel(
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  setup_data()

  # rest of app goes here....
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Doing it this way generates a cran NOTE of `no visible binding for '<<-' assignment`, and in general it is bad practise to do global assigns in a cran package.

Therefore, is there way I can create a function that does the setup like this, but in a way conducive to shiny and cran packages? Ideally I'd like to avoid returning everything in a `list`, and I haven't found a way to make this work in the Shiny Modules framework as there is no corresponding UI to tie these to.

Is there any other options?

Comment: Is it possible to setup the data using the `global.R`-file? "Any R objects that are created in the global.R file become available to the app.R file, or the ui.R and server.R files respectively!" More info: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Comment: Yep, thats actually a really good solution! Feel free to contribute that as an asnwer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup the data using the `global.R` file. Any R objects that are created in the global.R file become available to the app.R file, or the ui.R and server.R files respectively. [Take a look at how to modularize shiny apps.](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, you can use `local = TRUE` to only load objects into the shiny environment.

Comment: Using a `global.R` seems to load things into the R global environment (which is then available to shiny). Do you know whether its possible to just load them into Shinys environment?

Comment: Ah, `local = TRUE` does it

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include that information, as I wasn't aware of it!

Comment: `local = TRUE` as an argument... for what function/method?

Comment: @Ego Ipse > to the `source()`